# Possible to stop ASP.NET event using jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have some code like below in an aspx page:

```
function CheckEditing() {
      var answer = confirm('You are currently editing an item.  If you continue to the next page your changes will not be saved.  Would you like to continue?');
      if(!answer)
      {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
}

<asp:Button ID="btn_Next" runat="server" Text="Next" onclick="btn_Next_Click" OnClientClick="CheckEditing();" />
```

I had thought that returning false would keep my asp.net OnClick even from firing, but it still does.  I've confirmed that it is getting to the `return false` section of code using alerts.  Is there anything I can do to stop it from firing using jQuery/javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `OnClientClick` like this:

```
OnClientClick="if(!CheckEditing()) return false;"
```

Because it renders as `if(!CheckEditing()) return false; ASPNetFunction()` you wouldn't want to return outright, or the second function would *never* run.

Comment: Isn't that the same thing that i'm doing now?

Comment: @Abe - Nope, you're calling it, but not doing a `return false` overall...currently your `return false` in the function isn't being used for anything outside the function, like cancelling the `onclick` handler :)

Comment: To add to Nicks response. You could keep you JS function the same and just put `OnClientClick="return CheckEditing();"`

Comment: @Dustin - You can't *always*, for the reasons I laid out above :) There's a function *after* this one that needs to be called.

Comment: @Nick, hmm it worked for me.  Does it make a difference that one is on the client click event?

Comment: @Abe - Depending on the .net version, it'll fix this for you, I posted the always safe route :)

Comment: I think I see what I was missing, if he added an explicit return true at the end. That should work, correct?

Comment: @Dustin - Correct as well, it's always returning ~false at the moment :)

Comment: The __doPostBack() call in onclick should only appear if you've set UseSubmitBehavior to false.

Comment: Alright I added a `return true;` to the end.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this also, in this way.

Declare a custom validator with the appropriate client validation function

Now, as a part of your button, set the validation group to be the same as the custom validator

Inside the function CheckEditing(), set args.IsValid = false for not going onto the onClick event

Function CheckEditing(source,args)
{
   //...
   args.IsValid = false;
}